# What are these Two icons?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, quick-settings

I was re-ordering objects on the quick settings When I noticed two icons that I do not recognise:

[image]

To clarify, it's `HotKnot` and `BroadCastTile` That I am questioning.

Whats odder is that they are **not** in the Quick settings menu (Even if I add them)

[image]

What are they for, and how can I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>HotKnot</kbd> - The technology allows the capacitive touchscreens of smartphones to interact – a feature that can be used for quick data transfer/sharing, in a similar way to NFC.

Source: [link](https://blog.chinavasion.com/index.php/34848/what-is-hot-knot-and-how-to-use-it/)

<kbd>BroadCastTile</kbd> - It is just a customizable tile, you can add a custom tile if you know the constraints.

Source: [link](https://medium.com/@kcoppock/android-m-what-s-that-broadcast-tile-for-d1cd3a477a5f#.n3oelvatq)

Answer (score 0):

HotKnot is a kind of wireless communication like Bluetooth or NFC.

BroadcastTile is for creating your custom Quick Setting. See [here](https://medium.com/@kcoppock/android-m-what-s-that-broadcast-tile-for-d1cd3a477a5f#.8r6ozdnft).

Comment: Not audio profiles, the Android bot shaped one.

Comment: I edited my answer.